# How to limit same answer in form

Tags: php, html, forms, select

I have a form with dropdown choice

```
<select id="ubytovanie" name="ubytovanie">
        <option value="">  </option>
        <option value="1"> 1 </option>
        <option value="2"> 2 </option>
        <option value="3"> 3 </option>
        <option value="4"> 4 </option>
        <option value="5"> 5 </option>
        <option value="6"> 6 </option>
        <option value="7"> 7 </option>
        <option value="8"> 8 </option>
        <option value="9"> 9 </option>
        <option value="10"> 10 </option>
        <option value="11"> 11 </option>
        <option value="12"> 12 </option>
      </select>
```

In my form you can choose room number in which you would like to stay. But there can be only 6 people in one room, so I need to limit the option so max 6 people can choose same room number. After that, the option with room number would be disabled for other people filling out the form.

Is there a way to do this, ideally with PHP?
Thanks for answer

Comment: Sure, but you need to try something and show us first.

Comment: You should rather do this on the server, excluding any options with rooms that are fully booked. Doing this in Javascript increases the amount of data to be sent to the client and also opens your application to manipulation(what if the user manually shows or enables the option and submits the booking?)

Comment: Doing this on the client side is for good user experience, but server side validation is definitely needed. I don;t think they conflict each other.